# Date, startdate minus enddate equal to total

Tags: php, datetimepicker

I create **start date** with datetime picker and **end date** with datetime picker.

Example like this :

```
start date = 19/05/2018 (if user choose date now)

end date = 21/05/2018 (if user choose the end date)

total = 2 days (and show total, start date - end date = total)
```

How to create `start date - end date = total`?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Timepickers are not normally done with PHP, so there's a lot of context / information missing in your question to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of calculating it in PHP (>=5.3.0, 7):

```
$startdate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '19/05/2018');
$enddate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '21/05/2018');
$interval = $startdate->diff($enddate);
$total = $interval->d;
```